# Add table of contents in an "article class" based Curriculum Vitae template

Tags: article, cv

My curriculum vitae latex document is modelled after Ted Pavlic's http://links.tedpavlic.com/tex/tpavlic_cv_faculty.tex (here is the output: http://www.tedpavlic.com/facjobsearch/docs/tpavlic_cv.pdf)

This template works very well for me, but I'd like to ask: how can I add a table of contents right after the "CONTACT INFORMATION" section? This table of contents should contain the section headings (CONTACT INFORMATION, RESEARCH INTERESTS, and so on) along with the page number they are on.

Comment: Do you mean a table of contents?

Comment: You should ask the author of the template.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this for example with package `titletoc` to get a low space consuming TOC.

Add in the preamble the following code

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{0em}%2.55em toc right margin
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section{\contentsname}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{section}[0pt]
  {}{}{}
  {, \thecontentspage}[\ \textbullet\ ][.]
\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{}
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

and where you want to have your Table of contents the following code:

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents} % <=======================
\tableofcontents % <====================================================
```

With the following complete Code

```
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Simple LaTeX CV Template %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% NOTE: If you find that it says                                     %%
%%                                                                    %%
%%                           1 of ??                                  %%
%%                                                                    %%
%% at the bottom of your first page, this means that the AUX file     %%
%% was not available when you ran LaTeX on this source. Simply RERUN  %%
%% LaTeX to get the ``??'' replaced with the number of the last page  %%
%% of the document. The AUX file will be generated on the first run   %%
%% of LaTeX and used on the second run to fill in all of the          %%
%% references.                                                        %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Document Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Don't like 10pt? Try 11pt or 12pt
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

% LaTeX will typeset using Computer Modern Roman, which a lot of
% non-mathematicians and non-engineers won't like. Also, a few PDF
% viewers may not render CMR very well. Instead, Times New Roman can
% be used. That's what this package does.
\usepackage{times}

% The automated optical recognition software used to digitize resume
% information works best with fonts that do not have serifs. This
% command uses a sans serif font throughout. Uncomment both lines (or at
% least the second) to restore a Roman font (i.e., a font with serifs).
% (NOTE: This requires the times package above)
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% This is a helpful package that puts math inside length specifications
\usepackage{calc}

% This package helps LaTeX auto-hyphenate hyphenated words if you use
% special hyphens. For example, bio\-/mimicry will properly hyphenate
% ``mimicry'' if necessary.
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}

% Layout: Puts the section titles on left side of page
\reversemarginpar

%
%         PAPER SIZE, PAGE NUMBER, AND DOCUMENT LAYOUT NOTES:
%
% The next \usepackage line changes the layout for CV style section
% headings as marginal notes. It also sets up the paper size as either
% letter or A4. By default, letter was used. If A4 paper is desired,
% comment out the letterpaper lines and uncomment the a4paper lines.
%
% As you can see, the margin widths and section title widths can be
% easily adjusted.
%
% ALSO: Notice that the includefoot option can be commented OUT in order
% to put the PAGE NUMBER *IN* the bottom margin. This will make the
% effective text area larger.
%
% IF YOU WISH TO REMOVE THE ``of LASTPAGE'' next to each page number,
% see the note about the +LP and -LP lines below. Comment out the +LP
% and uncomment the -LP.
%
% IF YOU WISH TO REMOVE PAGE NUMBERS, be sure that the includefoot line
% is uncommented and ALSO uncomment the \pagestyle{empty} a few lines
% below.
%

%% Use these lines for letter-sized paper
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            %includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
            marginparwidth=1.2in,     % Length of section titles
            marginparsep=.05in,       % Space between titles and text
            margin=1in,               % 1 inch margins
            includemp]{geometry}

%% Use these lines for A4-sized paper
%\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
%            %includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
%            marginparwidth=30.5mm,    % Length of section titles
%            marginparsep=1.5mm,       % Space between titles and text
%            margin=25mm,              % 25mm margins
%            includemp]{geometry}

%% More layout: Get rid of indenting throughout entire document
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

% Provides special list environments and macros to create new ones
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% Simpler bibsections for CV sections
% (thanks to natbib for inspiration)
%
% * For lists of references with hanging indents and no numbers:
%
%   \begin{bibsection}
%       \item ...
%   \end{bibsection}
%
% * For numbered lists of references (with hanging indents):
%
%   \begin{bibenum}
%       \item ...
%   \end{bibenum}
%
%   Note that bibenum numbers continuously throughout. To reset the
%   counter, use
%
%   \restartlist{bibenum}
%
%   at the place where you want the numbering to reset.

\makeatletter
\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
\newlength{\bibsep}
 {\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
\newlist{bibsection}{itemize}{3}
\setlist[bibsection]{label=,leftmargin=\bibhang,%
        itemindent=-\bibhang,
        itemsep=\bibsep,parsep=\z@,partopsep=0pt,
        topsep=0pt}
\newlist{bibenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[bibenum]{label=[\arabic*],resume,leftmargin={\bibhang+\widthof{[999]}},%
        itemindent=-\bibhang,
        itemsep=\bibsep,parsep=\z@,partopsep=0pt,
        topsep=0pt}
\let\oldendbibenum\endbibenum
\def\endbibenum{\oldendbibenum\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}
\let\oldendbibsection\endbibsection
\def\endbibsection{\oldendbibsection\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}
\makeatother

%% Reference the last page in the page number
%
% NOTE: comment the +LP line and uncomment the -LP line to have page
%       numbers without the ``of ##'' last page reference)
%
% NOTE: uncomment the \pagestyle{empty} line to get rid of all page
%       numbers (make sure includefoot is commented out above)
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\pagestyle{empty}      % Uncomment this to get rid of page numbers
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
          {0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
       \parbox{4in}{\, \hfill %
                    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage} % +LP
%                    \arabic{page}                               % -LP
                    \hfill \,}}

% Finally, give us PDF bookmarks
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks,breaklinks,
  linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
  anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue
}

%\usepackage{showframe} % to visualize the typing area and margins

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{0em}%2.55em toc right margin
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section{\contentsname}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{section}[0pt]
  {}{}{}
  {, \thecontentspage}[\ \textbullet\ ][.]
\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{}
\makeatother % <========================================================
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Document Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Helper Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% HEADING AT TOP OF CURRICULUM VITAE

% The title (name) with a horizontal rule under it
% (optional argument typesets an object right-justified across from name
%  as well)
%
% Usage: \makeheading{name}
%        OR
%        \makeheading[right_object]{name}
%
% Place at top of document. It should be the first thing.
% If ``right_object'' is provided in the square-braced optional
% argument, it will be right justified on the same line as ``name'' at
% the top of the CV. For example:
%
%       \makeheading[\emph{Curriculum vitae}]{Your Name}
%
% will put an emphasized ``Curriculum vitae'' at the top of the document
% as a title. Likewise, a picture could be included:
%
%   \makeheading[{\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{my_picture}}]{Your Name}
%
% the picture will be flush right across from the name. For this example
% to work, make sure the extra set of curly braces is included. Also
% makes ure that \usepackage{graphicx} is somewhere in the preamble.
\newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
             {\large \bfseries #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

%%% SECTION HEADINGS

% The section headings. Flush left in small caps down pseudo-margin.
%
% Usage: \section{section name}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
    \vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\hyphenpenalty=10000\raggedright #1}}}%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}

%%% LISTS

% This macro alters a list by removing some of the space that follows the list
% (is used by lists below)
\newcommand*\fixendlist[1]{%
    \expandafter\let\csname preFixEndListend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{\csname preFixEndListend#1\endcsname\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}}

% These macros help ensure that items in outer-type lists do not get
% separated from the next line by a page break
% (they are used by lists below)
\let\originalItem\item
\newcommand*\fixouterlist[1]{%
    \expandafter\let\csname preFixOuterList#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\let\oldItem\item\def\item{\pagebreak[2]\oldItem}\csname preFixOuterList#1\endcsname}
    \expandafter\let\csname preFixOuterListend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{\let\item\oldItem\csname preFixOuterListend#1\endcsname}}
\newcommand*\fixinnerlist[1]{%
    \expandafter\let\csname preFixInnerList#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\let\oldItem\item\let\item\originalItem\csname preFixInnerList#1\endcsname}
    \expandafter\let\csname preFixInnerListend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{\csname preFixInnerListend#1\endcsname\let\item\oldItem}}

% An itemize-style list with lots of space between items
%
% Usage:
%   \begin{outerlist}
%       \item ...    % (or \item[] for no bullet)
%   \end{outerlist}
\newlist{outerlist}{itemize}{3}
    \setlist[outerlist]{label=\enskip\textbullet,leftmargin=*}
    \fixendlist{outerlist}
    \fixouterlist{outerlist}

% An environment IDENTICAL to outerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
%
% Usage:
%   \begin{lonelist}
%       \item ...    % (or \item[] for no bullet)
%   \end{lonelist}
\newlist{lonelist}{itemize}{3}
    \setlist[lonelist]{label=\enskip\textbullet,leftmargin=*,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
    \fixendlist{lonelist}
    \fixouterlist{lonelist}

% An itemize-style list with little space between items
%
% Usage:
%   \begin{innerlist}
%       \item ...    % (or \item[] for no bullet)
%   \end{innerlist}
\newlist{innerlist}{itemize}{3}
    \setlist[innerlist]{label=\enskip\textbullet,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
    \fixinnerlist{innerlist}

% An environment IDENTICAL to innerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
%
% Usage:
%   \begin{loneinnerlist}
%       \item ...    % (or \item[] for no bullet)
%   \end{loneinnerlist}
\newlist{loneinnerlist}{itemize}{3}
    \setlist[loneinnerlist]{label=\enskip\textbullet,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
    \fixendlist{loneinnerlist}
    \fixinnerlist{loneinnerlist}

%%% EXTRA SPACE

% To add some paragraph space between lines.
% This also tells LaTeX to preferably break a page on one of these gaps
% if there is a needed pagebreak nearby.
\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[3]}
\newcommand{\halfblankline}{\quad\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}\pagebreak[3]}

%%% FORMATTING MACROS

% Provides a linked \doi{#1} that links doi:#1 to http://dx.doi.org/#1
\usepackage{doi}
% To change the text before the DOI, adjust this command
%\renewcommand\doitext{doi:}

% Provides a linked \url{#1} that doesn't require escape characters
\usepackage{url}

% You can adjust the style \url{} uses here:
% (options are: same, rm, sf, tt; defaults to tt)
\urlstyle{same}

% For \email{ADDRESS}, links ADDRESS to the url mailto:ADDRESS
% (uncomment to typeset the e\-/mail address in typewriter font;
%  otherwise, will be typeset in the \urlstyle above)
%\DeclareUrlCommand\emaillink{\urlstyle{tt}}
\providecommand*\emaillink[1]{\nolinkurl{#1}}
\providecommand*\email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\emaillink{#1}}}

\providecommand\BibTeX{{B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em \TeX}}
\providecommand\Matlab{\textsc{Matlab}}

% Custom hyphenation rules for words that LaTeX has trouble with
\hyphenation{bio-mim-ic-ry bio-in-spi-ra-tion re-us-a-ble pro-vid-er Media-Wiki}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Helper Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin CV Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\makeheading{Dr.~Theodore~(Ted) P.~Pavlic}

\section{Contact Information}

% NOTE: Mind where the & separators and \\ breaks are in the following
%       table. Table is one row made up of three parboxes. The left
%       parbox has address info, the middle parbox has a vertical bar,
%       and the right parbox has phone and electronic contact
%       information.
%
% MACROS: \rcollength is the width of the right column of the table
%             (adjust it to your liking; default is 1.85in).
%         \spacewidth is width of area between left and right boxes.
%
\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{1.85in}%
\newlength{\spacewidth}\setlength{\spacewidth}{20pt}
%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}@{}p{\spacewidth}@{}p{\rcollength}}%

% Address box
\parbox{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}{%
%Assistant Professor\\
\href{http://www.asu.edu/}{Arizona State University}\\
\href{http://cidse.engineering.asu.edu/}{School of Computing, Informatics, and Decision Systems Engineering}\\
PO Box 878809, Room 553\\
Tempe, AZ  85287-8809  USA}

&
% Uncomment to add a vertical bar in middle of contact information
%{\vrule width 0.5pt}
\parbox[m][5\baselineskip]{\spacewidth}{} &

% Non-snail-mail contact information
\parbox{\rcollength}{%
\textit{Work:} +1-480-965-2899 \\
\textit{Fax:} +1-480-965-2751 \\
\textit{E-mail:} \email{tpavlic@asu.edu}\\
\textit{WWW:} \href{http://www.tedpavlic.com/}{www.tedpavlic.com}}

\end{tabular}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents} % <=======================
\tableofcontents % <====================================================

%%
%% In modern CV's, it seems like ``Objective'' is frowned upon. Instead,
%% incorporate it into a well-constructed cover letter. The ``More
%% information'' can go at the end of the CV, but it should not distract
%% from the section giving references available to contact.
%%
%
% \section{Objective}
%
% Placement in an academic position (i.e., faculty, postdoctoral, or
% research scientist) that allows for advanced research in distributed
% complex adaptive systems (i.e., modeling, analysis, design, and
% verification) with a particular focus on the control of engineered
% agents (e.g., for communications, control, software, electronics, and
% sustainability) and the analysis of biological phenomena (e.g.,
% self-organization, ecological rationality)
% \begin{innerlist}
% \item More information and auxiliary documents can be found at\\\url{http://www.tedpavlic.com/facjobsearch/}
% \end{innerlist}

\section{Research Interests}

\textbf{Complex adaptive systems in control systems engineering and
behavioral science:} distributed algorithms, computational agent-based
modeling, hybrid dynamic systems, decentralized decision making,
emergence and self organization, amorphous computing, autonomous
systems, control, communications, verification, cooperation,
optimization, game theory, resource allocation, parallel computation,
robotics, energy systems, sustainability in the built environment,
behavioral ecology, engineering education, bio-mimicry and
bio-inspiration

\section{Current Academic Appointments}

\textbf{Assistant Professor},
            \href{http://www.asu.edu/}{Arizona State University}
            \hfill {August 2015 to present}
\begin{innerlist}

    \item[] \href{http://cidse.engineering.asu.edu/}{School of Computing, Informatics, and Decision Systems Engineering}
    \item[] \href{http://sustainability.asu.edu/}{School of Sustainability}
    \begin{innerlist}
        \item Affiliations:
            \begin{innerlist}
                \item \href{http://sols.asu.edu}{School of Life Sciences} (Adjunct Professor)
                \item \href{http://biomimicry.asu.edu/}{The Biomimicry Center} (Associate Director of Research)
                \item \href{https://complexity.asu.edu/asu-sfi-center-biosocial-complex-systems}{ASU--Santa Fe Institute Center for Biosocial Complex Systems} (ASU--SFI Fellow)
                \item \href{http://barretthonors.asu.edu/}{Barrett, the Honors College} (Honors Faculty)
                \item \href{http://beyond.asu.edu/}{BEYOND Center for Fundamental Concepts in Science}
                \item \href{http://csdc.asu.edu/}{Center for Social Dynamics and Complexity}
                \item \href{http://sustainability.asu.edu/biodiversityoutcomes/}{Center for Biodiversity Outcomes}
                \item \href{http://globalsecurity.asu.edu/}{Global Security Initiative}
            \end{innerlist}
    \end{innerlist}

\end{innerlist}

\halfblankline

\textbf{External Faculty},
        \href{http://humancomputation.org/}{Human Computation Institute}
        \hfill {June 2015 to present}

\section{Previous Academic Appointments}

\textbf{Associate Research Scientist},
            \href{http://www.asu.edu/}{Arizona State University}
            \hfill {August 2014 to July 2015}
\begin{innerlist}

    \item[] \href{http://sols.asu.edu/}{School of Life Sciences}
    \begin{innerlist}
        \item Affiliations:
            \begin{innerlist}
                \item \href{http://cidse.engineering.asu.edu/}{School of Computing, Informatics, and Decision Systems Engineering}
                \item \href{http://beyond.asu.edu/}{BEYOND Center for Fundamental Concepts in Science}
                \item \href{http://csdc.asu.edu/}{Center for Social Dynamics and Complexity}
            \end{innerlist}
        \item Laboratories:
            \begin{innerlist}
                \item \href{http://www.public.asu.edu/~spratt1}{Stephen C.~Pratt's Collective Behavior Laboratory}
                \item \href{http://faculty.engineering.asu.edu/acs/}{Autonomous Collective Systems Laboratory} (PI: Spring Berman)
                \item \href{http://emergence.asu.edu/}{Emergence@ASU} (PI: Paul C. W. Davies, co-PI: Sara I. Walker)
            \end{innerlist}
    \end{innerlist}

\end{innerlist}

\halfblankline

\textbf{Postdoctoral Scholar},
            \href{http://www.asu.edu/}{Arizona State University}
            \hfill {July 2012 to August 2014}
\begin{innerlist}

    \item[] \href{http://sols.asu.edu/}{School of Life Sciences}
    \begin{innerlist}
        \item Supervisor: \href{http://www.public.asu.edu/~spratt1}{Professor Stephen C.~Pratt}
        \item Decentralized decision making and behavioral bio-mimicry
            of social insects
    \end{innerlist}

\end{innerlist}

\halfblankline

\textbf{Postdoctoral Researcher},
            \href{http://www.osu.edu/}{The Ohio State University}
            \hfill {September 2010 to June 2012}
\begin{innerlist}

    \item[] \href{http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/}{Department of Computer Science and Engineering}
    \begin{innerlist}
        \item \href{http://www.nfs.gov/}{NSF} ECCS-\href{http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=0931669}{0931669}:
                ``Autonomous Driving in Mixed-Traffic Urban Environments''
        \begin{innerlist}
            \item[$-$] Supervisor (co-PI):
                \href{http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~paolo/}%
                     {Professor Paolo A.~G.~Sivilotti}
            \item[$-$] PI:
                \href{http://www.ece.ohio-state.edu/~umit/}%
                     {Professor \"{U}mit \"{O}zg\"{u}ner}
        \end{innerlist}
    \end{innerlist}

\end{innerlist}

\section{Education}

\href{http://www.osu.edu/}{\textbf{The Ohio State University}},
Columbus, OH
\begin{outerlist}

\item[] Ph.D.,
        \href{http://www.ece.osu.edu/}
             {Electrical and Computer Engineering},
             August 2010
        \begin{innerlist}
        \item Thesis Topic: \emph{Design and Analysis of Optimal
            Task-Processing Agents}
        %\item Thesis Proposal: \emph{Cooperative Task Processing}
        \item Candidacy: \emph{Research
            Problems in Distributed Control for Energy Systems}
        \item Adviser:
              \href{http://www.ece.osu.edu/~passino/}
                   {Professor Kevin M.~Passino}
        \item Area of Study: Control Engineering
        \end{innerlist}

\item[] M.S.,
        \href{http://www.ece.osu.edu/}
             {Electrical and Computer Engineering}, August 2007
        \begin{innerlist}
        \item Thesis Topic: \emph{Optimal Foraging Theory Revisited}
        \item Adviser:
              \href{http://www.ece.osu.edu/~passino/}
                   {Professor Kevin M.~Passino}
        \item Area of Study: Control Engineering
        \end{innerlist}

\item[] B.S.,
        \href{http://www.ece.osu.edu/}
             {Electrical and Computer Engineering}, June 2004
        \begin{innerlist}
        \item \emph{Magna cum Laude}, With Honors in Engineering
        \item Electrical specialization (emphasis on electromagnetics and digital computers)
        \item Minor in \href{http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/}
                            {Computer and Information Systems}
              (programming and algorithms)
        \end{innerlist}

\end{outerlist}

% \section{Submitted Journal Publications}
%
% % Add a little space to nudge next ``Ref'd Journal Publications'' marginpar
% % down to make room for tall ``Submitted Journal Publications''
% % marginpar. If there are enough submitted journal publications, this
% % space will not be needed (and should be removed).
% \vspace{0.1in}

\section{Refereed Journal Publications}

\begin{bibenum}
    \item Wilson, S., T.P.~Pavlic, G.P.~Kumar, A.~Buffin, S.~Pratt, and
        S.~Berman. Design of ant-inspired stochastic control policies
        for collective transport by robotic swarms. \emph{Swarm
        Intelligence}, 8(4):303--327, December 2014.
        \doi{10.1007/s11721-014-0100-8}

    \item Pavlic, T.P., S.~Wilson, G.P.~Kumar, and S.~Berman. Control of
        stochastic boundary coverage by multi-robot systems.
        \emph{Journal of Dynamic Systems, Measurement, and Control
        [Special Issue on Stochastic Models, Control and Algorithms
        in Robotics]}, 137(3):034505, October~21, 2014.
        \doi{10.1115/1.4028353}

    \item Pavlic, T.P., and K.M.~Passino. Distributed and Cooperative
        Task Processing: Cournot Oligopolies on a Graph.
        \emph{IEEE Transactions on Cybernetics}, 44(6):774--784, June~2014.
        \doi{10.1109/TCYB.2013.2271776}

    \item Pavlic, T.P., and K.M.~Passino. Generalizing foraging theory
        for analysis and design. \emph{The International Journal of
        Robotics Research [Special Issue on Stochasticity in Robotics
        and Bio-Systems Part 1]}, 30(5):505--523, 2011.
        \doi{10.1177/0278364910396551}

    \item Pavlic, T.P., and K.M.~Passino. The sunk-cost effect as an
        optimal rate-maximizing behavior. \emph{Acta Biotheoretica},
        59(1):53--66, 2011.
        \doi{10.1007/s10441-010-9107-8}

    \item Pavlic, T.P., and K.M.~Passino. When rate maximization is
        impulsive. \emph{Behavioral Ecology and Sociobiology},
        64(8):1255--1265, August 2010.
        \doi{10.1007/s00265-010-0940-1}

    \item Pavlic, T.P., and K.M.~Passino. Foraging theory for autonomous
        vehicle speed choice. \emph{Engineering Applications of
        Artificial Intelligence}, 22(3):482--489, April 2009.\\
        \doi{10.1016/j.engappai.2008.10.017}
\end{bibenum}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting toc]

Comment: Seems the OP didn't bother to upvote ;-)